# Converting and Comparing Date

Tags: php

I came across a problem where when I **strtotime** date it gives me a value which is not equal to what I have in the database.

**Example:**

In the database I have this value

> 1398308880

Which is equal to this date

> 24/04/2014

So what I did is

```
$date = date('24/04/2014');
$date = strtotime($date);
```

Which gives me

> 1398297600

I can't understand, why is there a difference between both of them whereas they should be same value right? what am doing wrong here.

Comment: If those are in seconds, both are the same day. The first one is a couple hours later, but both are the same day. You're not crazy.

Comment: I' am banging my head now on the table, I might go crazy.

Comment: I don't know what's got in to you...

But what I see is that, I think your having a bad parameter on date function.

Try seeing [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

```
$time = '1398308880';
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $time);
// outputs 2014-04-23 22:08:00

echo '<br />';
echo mktime(22, 8, 0, 4, 24, 2014);
// outputs 1398395280
```

The timestamp is still different even when you account for the hour, minute and second. Why? I'm in a Chicago timezone. What timezone are you in? Or more importantly, is your database running in the same timezone as your PHP server?

Comment: It's maybe the timezone issue, I' am running on XAMPP Pacific/Fiji Timezone.